# Referencing external java model as an OpenAPI schema

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, modelmapper

Gradle, OpenAPI 3.0.x, Spring Boot

Project Structure: com.common (sub project 1), com.springboot.project (sub project 2)

How can we reference the model from com.common.models.Pet, as a Schema under open-api.yml under springboot project?

Consider the following,

1. Need to reference just one model. not all the models under com.common.models.
2. Common project is not a boot project.

Note: com.company.generated.models are under com.springboot.project

1. I am aware of using ModelMappers, and I think this makes me add to much code

```java
com.common.models.PetModel petModel = ..something which game me my petModel
com.company.generated.models.PetModel convertedModel =
                    petModel.stream()
                            .map(source -> modelMapper.map(source, com.company.generated.models.PerModel.class)
```

2. I tried to import the model mapping as a config option under the OpenAPI gradle task like below - However, the generator is directing the model creation to all the models in the directory, not just Pet.

```java
configOptions: [

modelMappings: "com.companyname.generated.models=com.common.models"

]
```

3. I tried to add a specific model name such as,

```java
configOptions: [

modelMappings: "PetModel=com.common.models.PetModel"

]
```